# Xamarin C# mobile app not able to call API hosted on local system through mobile phone

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I have created a mobile app in C# Xamarin. I have consumed a webapi hosted on my local system through this app.
It runs on my local xamarin studio.

But it does not work when the app is installed on any Phone over same network.
Code is:

**

```
var request = new RestRequest ("/api/values", Method.GET);
                var client = new RestClient (@"http://anuj2819:90");
                client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
                    GetName (response.Content);
                });
```

**

if I use any api hosted on internet such as

**

```
var request = new RestRequest ("/posts/1", Method.GET);
var client = new RestClient (@"http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");
```

**

it works on the app on phone as well.

Please suggest.

Comment: I am using bluestacks to test my app on same system.

Comment: Set up port forwarding in your router ...

Comment: Try specifying the IP of your server.  Your phone probably is unable to lookup "anuj2819"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The way I solved it was by using the IP address of my computer

public const string APIBaseAddress = "http://192.168.1.64/api/";

and opening the firewall on my computer to receive http requests